# KnockOut script not updating Input

Tags: knockout.js

Hello I have little problem with my simple script. I have a button which when pressed should write something into the input which is bind with knockout ViewModel.

But for unknow me reason my code is updating observable but the input remains empty.

Here my html code:

```
<div class="col-lg-3">
    <div class="input-group">
        <span class="input-group-addon">User</span>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="text:DeviceUser" required name="User" id="User" />
    </div>
</div>
<div class="col-lg-2">
    <div class="input-group">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="UserClick" data-bind="event:{click: click}">Add me as a user</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here script:

```
var ViewModel = function () {
    var self = this;

    self.DeviceUser = ko.observable();

    self.click = function () {
        var temp = "NewValue";
        self.DeviceUser(temp);
        alert(self.DeviceUser())
    }
};

var model = new ViewModel();
ko.applyBindings(model);
```

can anyone tell me what should I change in order to make it work?

Here you can check live sample on [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/CJrR4/)

Comment: You can also replace `data-bind="event:{click: click}"` by `data-bind="click: click"`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You use invalid binding for input. It should be `value`, instead `text`:

```
<input type="text" class="form-control" data-bind="value:DeviceUser" required name="User" id="User" />
```